# Selecionando atributos do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, atributos

Bom, estou tendo problemas ao selecionar um atributo de um determinado elemento do `bootstrap` com o `jquery`, por exemplo:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carrossel-principal" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carrossel-principal" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carrossel-principal" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

- Para selecionar o `data-target`, ou `data-slide-to`, e seus respectivos valores, como poderia ser feito tal procedimento ?
- O mesmo procedimento é válido para qualquer outro atributo ?
- Como posso pegar o valor apenas do `data-slide-to` que possui classe `active` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se resolve:

```
$('.carousel-indicators li').data('slide-to');
$('.carousel-indicators').data('target');
```

Colocando `data` da forma que você colocou no HTML, funciona.

Comment: mas por exemplo, como posso fazer para pegar o valor do `data` que está com a classe ativo ?

Comment: Utilizando `$('li.active').data();`

Comment: perfeito cara, funcionou tranquilamente

Answer (score 2):

**DATA ATTRIBUTES**

Acrescentar atributos com dados (Data Attributes) visa a extensibilidade das tags em HTML5. Os atributos podem ser acessados de duas formas, via JavaScript puro ou jQuery.

Com JavaScript puro via `dataset` ([FONTE](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)):

```js
function mostrar() {
alert(document.getElementById('elemento').dataset.codigo);
}

/* Repare no uso do DATASET pois é ele que te permite acessar qualquer valor do tipo data-??? */
```

```html
<p data-codigo="18" onclick="mostrar()" id="elemento">Clique aqui!</div>
```

E com jQuery via `.data()` ([FONTE](https://api.jquery.com/data/)):

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  alert($('div').data('qualquer'));
});

/* a função .data() permite capturar atributos data- */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-qualquer="Trabalhando com data-">Clique Aqui!</div>
```